# Error in write.table for R code Yahoo Finance data dump

Tags: r, yahoo, finance

I am using R to download stock data from Yahoo Finance. This code was working this morning, but I am now getting the error message:

```
Error in write.table(d, file = "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\MMM.csv",  : 
  invalid 'row.names' specification".
```

I am pretty new to R so I am not sure what is causing the error. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("MMM", from = "2012/06/29" , to = "2013/06/29")
[1] "MMM"
d=as.data.frame(MMM)
d=cbind(datestamp=rownames(d),d)
write.csv(d,file= "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\MMM.csv",row.names=F)
Error in write.table(d, file = "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\MMM.csv",  : 
  invalid 'row.names' specification
```

Comment: maybe `F` is defined differently. Did you try `row.names=FALSE`?

Comment: Thank you changing to False fixed it. Strange that it switched...

Comment: It is not strange, that's how it works... `F` is short for `FALSE` unless you do create a `F` variable. This is why 1) using `F` as short for `FALSE` and 2) using `F` as a variable name are both very bad ideas. Same goes for `T` and `TRUE`.